# Would converting energy directly into mass be the ultimate cooling system?

Tags: special-relativity, energy

So i'll preface this with saying that I'm not super qualified in physics so this might be totally wrong, but I've been thinking about this recently and I figured that I could get an answer here.

We know that $E=mc^2$ from Einstein and we know that the goal of a cooling solution is to get rid of energy from a system. Would it then follow that at least hypothetically, the best cooling solution for future computers or whatever would have a direct output of some atoms?

Would a system like this at all make sense with modern technology?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A good answer to this question should mention entropy.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Idea.

If you get your computer to run at 12 Billion Kelvin, it might be possible. But than you would not want to be near that computer. One of the reasons is that it will emit gamma radiation at that temperature.

There are a few details that make it implausible to be of any use in the forseeable future because turning [energy into matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_creation) is not easy:

- the conversion is "not very efficient" (means, we need to put in an insane amount of additional energy to convert photons to matter)
- we need really high energies like in a big particle accelerator (above 1 MeV). That's in the range of soft gamma rays.

Heat output from normal computers produces really low energy infrared photons (0.03eV at 100°C). That's not enough energy to form matter from photons. You'd need to heat the computer up to almost 12 billion Kelvon (11,859,824,556 K) to give the photons the energy to have a chance to form matter when two photons collide.

For the Kelvin to eV conversion I've used this [Unit Converter](https://www.unitsconverters.com/en/Kelvin-To-Electron-Volt/Unittounit-3514-3462).

Comment: Indeed a very good spot, one needs about $20~\text{million}$ infrared photons for producing just a single electron ! Crazingly inefficient conversion ;-)

Comment: That would be a nice one for randall munroe of xkcd... It include high energy physics, radiation and the potential for destroying earth :)